# VB.NET Problemas al abrir una carpeta

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un problema al abrir una carpeta. Tengo un windows form con varios botones, 2 concretamente realizan la misma función, comprobar si existe la carpeta en la ruta especificada, eliminarla en el caso de que exista y crearla nuevamente. A su vez descomprime unos archivos en la carpeta indicada y abre esta. En el VS funciona correctamente pero cuando lo convierto en un exe uno de los 2 botones(que tienen exactamente el mismo código exceptuando el nombre de la carpeta) hace todo pero no abre la carpeta al final.

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If IO.Directory.Exists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar") Then
        IO.Directory.Delete(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar", True)
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar")
    Else
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar")
    End If
    Try

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar_wind.zip", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar")
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If IO.Directory.Exists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay") Then
        IO.Directory.Delete(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay", True)
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay")
    Else
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay")
    End If
    Try

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay_wind.zip", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay")
```

¿En donde he cometido el error?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Es posible que sea un tema de permisos? Intenta ejecutar tu `exe` como administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Pues no le veo error a tu código. Lo único que hice fue cambiar el ZipFile por System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, y el código me quedó así

```
Imports System.IO.Compression.ZipFile

Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      If IO.Directory.Exists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar") Then
         IO.Directory.Delete(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar", True)
         IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar")
      Else
         IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar")
      End If

      Try
         System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar_wind.zip", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar")
      Catch ex As Exception

      End Try

      Process.Start("explorer.exe", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Gibraltar")
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
      If IO.Directory.Exists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay") Then
         IO.Directory.Delete(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay", True)
         IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay")
      Else
         IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay")
      End If
      Try

         System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay_wind.zip", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay")
      Catch ex As Exception

      End Try

      Process.Start("explorer.exe", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Biscay")
   End Sub
End Class
```

y así funcinoa perfectamente, abre ambas carpetas y descomprime el archivo.